# sr.ReadLine() isn't receiving data that is being sent

Tags: c#, .net-core, stream, network-programming

I am trying to implement an authentication method for my program. I have a server-side program that handles authentication:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(9120);
        public const string DECRYPT_KEY = "KObOBonONoinbOClHNKYJkgIKUFkjfKcvCYckcvBBCVKcbvHHCxthjcTJYBXJahjh";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                if (listener.Pending())
                {
                    new Thread(TryAuthenticate).Start();
                }
            }
        }

        static void TryAuthenticate()
        {
            TcpClient needsAuth = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(needsAuth.GetStream());
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (!line.StartsWith("AUTH? ")) return;

            StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader("keys.pks");

            string line2;

            while ((line2 = sr2.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line == line2)
                {
                    new StreamWriter(needsAuth.GetStream()).WriteLine("AFFIRMATIVE");
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }

            sr2.Close();
            needsAuth.Close();
        }
    }
```

And on the client-side I have this code:

```cs
    class Authentication
    {
        public static bool Authenticate(string id)
        {
            if (id == "dEbUg2020") return true;

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 9120);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            sw.WriteLine("AUTH? " + id);
            if (sr.ReadLine() == "AFFIRMATIVE")
            {
                sw.Close();
                sr.Close();
                client.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                sw.Close();
                sr.Close();
                client.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried debugging on both the client and the server side.

On the client-side, it starts hanging at `if (sr.ReadLine() == "AFFIRMATIVE")`.

On the server-side, it starts hanging at `string line = sr.ReadLine();`.

I have done some research and it has told me that when `sr.ReadLine()` is expecting data but doesn't get any, it hangs until it does.

But I have sent data, and both the client/server hangs indefinitely until it crashes. I am stuck, does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Try Adding sw.Flush() in client code just after sw.WriteLine(). StreamReader has an internal buffer and it will not try to write actually until you dispose stream or call Flush() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing a message with your sw StreamWriter, you need to flush it with `sw.Flush();` for it to actually be sent to the other side.

So

```
sw.WriteLine("Some line");
sw.Flush();
```

Otherwise, you're not sending anything.

Comment: Thank you. I was calling Stream.Flush before instead of sw.Flush and it didn't work so i tried getting rid of it. thank you, it works!